# Convert milliseconds to string %H%M%S.%f

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime, python-3.9

I'm trying to convert time in milliseconds to time in a string with milliseconds.

```
import datetime

x = 23500
j = x / 1000.0
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(j).strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f'))
```

The result is '03:00:23.500000'.

And this is not true. 23500 ms is not 3 hours 23 seconds, but only 23 seconds.

The module time allows me correct conversion, but does not display milliseconds.

Can someone explain to me why the datetime module does not give the correct value?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to use `timedelta` since apparently you’re dealing with a duration, not a timestamp.

Comment: I have no idea how to create a view string in the timedelta module. I'm trying to convert youtube xml subtitles to srt format. PyTube, which I use to download videos and subtitles, currently has a bug. This bug does not allow me to convert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create your timedelta object

```
from datetime import timedelta

ms = 23500
time = timedelta(milliseconds=ms)
```

now print the result

```
print(time) # output: 0:00:02.35
```

or save the result in a variable

```
result = str(time)
```